# Is there a way to change symbology with time in ArcGIS Desktop or Portal?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, timeslider

I have a time-enabled layer that I am interacting with through Arc's time slider. Now, I'd like to change symbology with time. More specifically, I want my features to change color with every year.

Is there a way to do this in Desktop or Portal? If so, how?

I'm not looking for answers that suggest creating new features for each year. Before I do something like that, I want to be sure the functionality doesn't already exist somewhere.